# .htaccess rewrite url with letters öäå and passing variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

Lets say survey name is test.

When completing form it redirects to
[www.example.com/survey_thank_you.php?survey_name=test](http://www.example.com/survey_thank_you.php?survey_name=test)

then rewrites it to [www.example.com/test/thank_you](http://www.example.com/test/thank_you) and it works as inteded.

**But because here we use öäå the issue emerge. If survey name is testä, it redirects allright but rewrites it to
[www.example.com/test%25C3%25A4/thank_you](http://www.example.com/test%25C3%25A4/thank_you) (this works)
and it should rewrite to [www.example.com/testä/thank_you](http://www.example.com/test%C3%A4/thank_you)**

also if go straight to [www.example.com/testä/thank_you](http://www.example.com/test%C3%A4/thank_you) it works.

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8


RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^survey_name=(.*)/?$
RewriteRule ^survey_thank_you\.php$ /%1/thank_you [R,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/thank_you$ survey_thank_you.php?survey_name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ survey_form.php?survey_name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If i change (.*) to ([0-9a-zA-Z]+) it rewrites it allright /testä/thank_you but then i get error 404. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell what actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here.

Comment: Edited question, bolded out the issue.

Comment: If going "straight" to `www.example.com/testä/thank_you` works, but being redirected to `/testä/thank_you` doesn't, then you probably have an issue with what encoding these characters are getting interpreted in somewhere along the way. But such characters should not be used without proper URL encoding to begin with. If you leave it up to the client to apply the URL encoding, then you are bound to run into such issues.

Comment: `test%25C3%25A4` would be the result of _double_ URL encoding though. One level decoded, leaves `test%C3%A4`. You could try and use the `NE` flag to try and avoid double encoding at this place, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: Are you positive it's an Apache issue, and not you passing a urlencoded variable that's duly rewritten as-is?

Comment: @CBroe You were right, can you make answer so i can aprove it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test%25C3%25A4` would be the result of *double* URL encoding. One level decoded, leaves `test%C3%A4`.

You can use the `NE` flag to try and avoid double encoding in this place, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne